# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: cures (code 1):

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

1. I have changed the database user version
2. In the class I have created, I have changed the version no in the super(...)
3. In onupgrade method, I have deleted the database and created a new database through copy from the app.
4. I have checked all answers at stackoverflow on this problem. Every compile seems to fail.

I have tried the net for a solution which seems to evade me.

I would appreciate some help.

The class is as follows:

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // DBPATH uses the default system path for a given application
    // /data/data/<app namespace> , which in our example will be
    // com.wordpress.arogyavidya.mooligaimarmam
    private static String DBPATH = "/data/data/com.wordpress.arogyavidya.mooligaimarmam/databases/";
    private static String DBNAME = "mooligaimarmam.db";
    //  private static String DATABASE_TABLE = "lkgchef";
//  static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
//  static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
//  static final String KEY_DETAIL = "desc";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    // constructor
    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 3);
        this.myContext = context;
        //DBPATH = this.myContext.getDatabasePath("mooligaimarmam.db").getPath();
    }

    // create an empty db, and replace with our chosen db
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        if (!checkDatabase()) {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database from system assets");
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if our database already exists
    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkableDatabase = null;
        try {
            checkableDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPATH+DBNAME,
                    null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // our database doesn't exist, so we'll return false below.
        }
        if (checkableDatabase != null) {
            checkableDatabase.close();
        }
        return checkableDatabase != null ? true : false;
    }

    // Copy our database from the Application's assets over the empty DB for use
    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DBPATH+DBNAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPATH + DBNAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        /*myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPATH, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);*/
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDatabase != null)
            myDatabase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Handle creation tasks, etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Handle upgrade tasks, etc.
        myDatabase.close();
        myContext.deleteDatabase(DBPATH+DBNAME);

        try {
            this.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database from system assets");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you only call createDatabase in onUpgrade. If you are not in this situation, you are not creating your database

Comment: uninstall the application on the device and then reinstall or update the dbversion in code

Comment: What do you mean with "Every compile seems to fail"?

Answer (score 0):

try this once! dont delete the database, just drop the table. this works for me everytime.

```
 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Name);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: The database with static data is pre-created and is part of the .apk.

Comment: I initially changed the version number in DBAdapter. Later, I chnged the user version in database also. However, after uploading to play store, crashes were observed though during testing no crashes were observed. The documentation does not say how to go about it. Through stackoverflow I found it after a lot of difficulty, I discovered my mistake.